# How to create a branch in GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I'm learning Git and experimenting. I understand how to do basic operations but am struggling with creating a new branch. I'm using the command prompt in windows and the github tool in a browser. I have attempted to simulate the creation of a new branch by making a new branch (named branch_1) in the browser, but when I try to find that branch in the command prompt, it does not show up. For example, here's what I get in the command prompt:

```
git branch
 _notes/dwsync.xml
master
v1.1
v1.2
v1.3
```

How do I get the new branch to appear?

Comment: The browser creates the branch directly in the remote github project. Not in your working copy. Use git pull to synchronize the working copy with the changes made in the remote repo. You should usually do the reverse: create your branch locally using the command line, make changes in your branch, commit, and push the branch.

Answer (score 7):

You do these steps:

```
git checkout -b your_branch
git push -u origin your_branch
```

show all branches (see result):

```
git branch
```

Reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

Answer (score 5):

When you create a branch in github, it's in the github remote. You need to fetch the branch from that remote, to your local, and tell your local to track that branch.

`git fetch <remote_name> <branch_name>`

`git checkout --track <remote_name>/<branch_name>`

This assumes you want the branch_name on the remote to be the same on your local.

Answer (score 2):

A branch is a lightweight thing in git, it is just a sticky note pointing to a commit. Actually, it is even lighter than a tag (which has additional attributes).

You normally create branches locally. If you want to create a branch `newbranch` starting off at `oldcommit` (which can, as always, be a commit hash, a branch name, a tag name or some other more obscure things), then you basically have two equivalent ways of doing that:

```
git checkout oldcommit
git checkout -b newbranch
```

or

```
git branch newbranch oldcommit
git checkout newbranch
```

It's a matter of taste, I prefer the first one.

To push the branch to the remote `origin`:

```
git push origin newbranch
```

I suggest you get very familiar with working with branches, you will be doing it all the time, and it should really feel easy and spontaneous to you. This is one of the major benefits of using `git` over other versioning systems.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a new branche in github with the browser you must pull it in your local repo
so you do :
git pull and after you execute : 
git branch

Answer (score 0):

git checkout -b 'branchname'

this will create a new branch and transfer you there from the master